# Changing the .html of each <td> on click

Tags: php, jquery, html, this, each

This is my first attempt using `this` from scratch, I'm not sure I understand it correctly. I'm trying to change whichever `<td>` that has a `+` in it to a `-` on click and vice versa. 
I'm not getting any errors and I'm not sure what specifically I'm doing wrong. Nothing happens on click. I have other jquery on the page that works fine.

```
echo "<script type'text/javascript'>
$('.plus_minus').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
        if ($(this).html() == '+'){
            $(this).html = '-';
        }
        else {
            $(this).html = '+';
        }

    })
 });

</script>";
```

the html looks like

```
echo '<tr align="right" class="loc"><td class="plus_minus" width="20" align="center" 
            bordercolor="#000000"
            style="cursor:pointer;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;
            border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">+</td>';
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1. Open developers console. 2. `$(this).html('-');`

Comment: you're trying to assign a click handler to ever .plusminus class, which is the wrong way of doing it.you should have one handler which takes care of them all, e.g. `$(.plus_minus).on('click', function(e) { $(this).html ... });`

Comment: @MarcB I changed it to `$('.plus_minus').on('click', function(e) {` and then what I had above, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.plus_minus').each(function() {
   $(this).click(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == '+'){
            $(this).text('-');
        }
        else {
            $(this).text('+');
        }

   })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr align="right" class="loc"><td class="plus_minus" width="20" align="center" 
            bordercolor="#000000"
            style="cursor:pointer;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;
            border-style:solid;border-width:1pt">+</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this worked! I guess it was .html that was the culprit